# Tensorflow model.save() doesn't save the model's inference function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a class which extends `keras.Model` and implements a model made out of several standard layers and custom ones.
I'm not using `model.fit()` but rather a `for` loop to iterate over the data and run the following training step function

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        inputs = batch[0] + [batch[1][-1]]
        predictions, _ = model(inputs, training=True)
        loss = log_likelihood(batch[1], predictions, batch[2])
        regularisation_loss = model.output_layers.losses

    gradients = tape.gradient([regularisation_loss, loss], model.trainable_variables)
    optimiser.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

For saving, I'm simply calling `model.save(model_path)`.
Everything goes fine until I try to reload a saved model. The loading calls throws (just the bottom lines)

```
  File "..\.conda\envs\tf.2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\function_deserialization.py", line 265, in recreate_function
    concrete_function_objects.append(concrete_functions[concrete_function_name])
KeyError: '__inference_model_layer_call_fn_37936'
```

This, I assume, refers to the main `call` function of my model which is just not serialised and saved from some reason. I looked into `concrete_functions` and pretty much everything was in there except for this one function. I tried this with and without the `tf.function` decorator and saw no difference.
I'm sort of lost now and would really appreciate not just an answer, but also a good direction for debugging.

Thanks

Comment: What are my cusom objects then? my loss doesn't seem to be the problem here and the `model.call` function should also be serialise to this `__inference...` function. I'm not even sure what to provide as a name there. I've tried it with `'__inference_model_layer_call_fn_37936': Model.call` but it didn't really work

Comment: My loss function is decorated with `@tf.function` so it should be serialised and saved with the model. Nevertheless, I've tried specifying the loss function (both with and without the decorator) and it also didn't work. Furthermore the error clearly states that it looks for the inference function for the entire model, i.e. model.call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a discussion in
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42004
which set me in the right direction, I did the following changes which seem to have solved the problem

1. All Model implementations, except for the "main model wrapper thingy", were changes to Layer objects.
2. All custom implementations (both the Layers and the Model) were given a get_config function.

I'm not sure which of these did the trick, but my money is on the first point.